# loading data (posts) from firebase (real time database ) not working in time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, vite, redux-toolkit

I have a function called loadMore which gets data from firebase , using currentuserIndex as index , in first useEffect the loadMore is called succusfully but it's not getting data (posts) and render it .

that's the code .
this code works only when I update it manually , (when I click on code and click save the changes apears and it works fine).
also I'm using redux tool-kit just to achieve some performance and not loading posts from start evry time user navigate back to Home page.

```
import "./style/style.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import PostCard from "../../Components/HomeCard/PostCard";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/compat";
import "firebase/database";
import { Loadposts } from "../../Config/LoadPosts";
import shuffle from "lodash/shuffle";


export default function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [userIds, setUserIds] = useState([]);
  const [currentUserIdIndex, setCurrentUserIdIndex] = useState(0);
  const reduxPosts = useSelector((state) => state.LoadPosts.posts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const rendered = {};

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.database().ref("/");
    usersRef.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
      const users = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
      const shuffledUsers = shuffle(users);
      setUserIds(shuffledUsers);
    }).then(()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        ()=>{
          loadMore()
        }
      },1500)
    })
  }, []);
  

  const loadMore = () => {
    const username = userIds[currentUserIdIndex];
    console.log("Loadmore has been called x2")

    const dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`${username}`);
    let query = dbRef.child("posts").orderByKey().limitToFirst(5);
    query.on("value", (snapshot) => {
      const postList = [];
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const key = childSnapshot.key;
        const post = childSnapshot.val();
        postList.push({ key, ...post });
      });

      if (postList.length) {
        dispatch(Loadposts([...postList]));
      }
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (currentUserIdIndex < userIds.length) {
        setCurrentUserIdIndex(currentUserIdIndex + 1);
        loadMore();
      }
    }, 2900);
    return () => query.off();
  };

  ///detecting user movements
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [currentUserIdIndex]);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrollY, innerHeight } = window;
    const { scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;
    if (scrollY + innerHeight >= scrollHeight) {
      if (currentUserIdIndex < userIds.length) {
        setCurrentUserIdIndex(currentUserIdIndex + 1);
        loadMore();
      }
    }
    return;
  };
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="container">
        {reduxPosts &&
          Object.entries(reduxPosts).map(([key, post]) => {
            if (rendered[post.key] || !post.img) {
              return;
            }
            rendered[post.key] = true;
            return (
              <PostCard post={post} cle={post.key + key} key={post.key + key} />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}`.
```

it should get posts at the first time as useEffect run , and user can see posts in Home page . please help me I'll be happy.